# How to use a user defined save location in InstallShield?

Tags: c++, installation

Is there a way to use the path that a user defines during an install in a custom action?

I have an installer that I am creating. During the install process, it will ask the user where they would like to put the install. Part of the installer uses a separate .exe during a custom action. In that .exe (in the custom action), I want to be able to access the install location the user chose. Is that possible?

**More Info:**

So in my installer, I have a couple of files that I want to move to another folder once the install is complete. These files I want to move are in the [ProgramFilesFolder]. The .exe (a c++ project) for the custom action I have put in the [AppDataFolder]. The custom action occurs in the "After Register Product" stage of the installation.

In my .exe, I want to get the install directory for the application and send it to a .bat file. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the generic answer is it is possible.

But you have to be more specific in your question, if you want to know how it can be done in your case.

As for now I'll suggest following possibilities for you

1. Define an environment variable and set the value to it from the
   installer, then read it from .exe
2. Pass the user input parameter as an input parameter to your executable.
3. etc.

Need more help then provide more info